# STL: calling bind2nd with ptr_fun for "const T &" types

Tags: c++, stl, adaptor

Calling

```
std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(foo), 17))
```

works fine with

```
bool foo(int, int),
```

but I can't make it work with

```
bool foo(const int &, const int &)
```

Is there a way to make that work or do I have to write my own adaptor function?

Comment: Why do you want to pass int's by const reference anyways? Any POD-type can be put on stack with no downsides.

Comment: It is not about int's in particular. I have more complex objects in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument is a number, and cannot be converted to `const int &`.

You can use `boost::bind` to do the trick:

```
std::count_if (vec.begin(), vec.end(), boost::bind (foo, _1, 17));
```

**EDIT**:

As of my first response, yes, you cannot use a variable instead of the number. I think the problem is `bind2nd` and `ptr_fun` not being properly defined to *dereference* the type in the case it is a reference when `ptr_fun` builds the internal `Operation` object, so ither go with boost or write your own functor class.

Comment: This doesn't make any difference. The error is: ‘typename _Operation::result_type std::binder2nd<_Operation>::operator()(typename _Operation::first_argument_type&) const [with _Operation = std::pointer_to_binary_function<const int&, const int&, bool>]’ cannot be overloaded with ‘typename _Operation::result_type std::binder2nd<_Operation>::operator()(const typename _Operation::first_argument_type&) const [with _Operation = std::pointer_to_binary_function<const int&, const int&, bool>]’